# CSS application on pseudo element after base element is created

Tags: jquery, css, pseudo-element

Is there any requirement about applying CSS on pseudo element only at the the time that the element is created and that it cannot be changed thereafter? Please read this carefully before marking it as a duplicate. I am not asking if you can change the css of a pseudo element directly, like by using the .css() method of Jquery.

Here is the exact sequence:

- CSS file is read which has the style for the pseudo element and
  the element.
- The element is created dynamically and its style changed
  dynamically.
- CSS is now changed dynamically on the pseudo element by
  replacing using JQuery the content of the "style" tag in which the style of the pseudo
  element is defined.

I do not see the style update on the pseudo element. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: How should we know what you're doing wrong when there's no code posted ?

Comment: As a sidenote, it seems to work perfectly fine -> http://jsfiddle.net/4enfJ/

Comment: @adeneo. The code is not relevant here. The question is a generic one: If a psuedo element is created and takes style from a static style tag, can I replace the content of that style tag using JS and expect the pseudo element to reflect the new css specified? I am only changing the width property. I just want to know before I start debugging. Does not make sense to do so if I am on the wrong footing to begin with. Thanks

Comment: The code is always relevant. As seen in the fiddle, it's not only possible, but quite simple, so if it's not working you're doing something wrong.

Comment: @adeneo. You are right. I looked at your code. I thought so too. I am doing the same. WOrked for me in a simple example too. Now that I know that it ought to work that way, let me look into the code and see where I am going wrong.  Thanks for confirming my doubt.

Comment: @adeneo. It was a stupid mistake... I forgot the px while specifying the length! Working in India... its 2:30 am. That explains it.